# How to refresh WordPress Customizer panel upon entering a value

Tags: themes, theme-customizer, api

I have created a variable number of fields to add images to a nivoslider. It works nicely, but I have to manually refresh the entire page and re-select the section from the customizer panel for the changes to take effect. I'm wondering if there is any way to get the customizer panel itself to refresh by php code, instead of just the live website area.

Here is the code

```
$wp_customize->add_section('slider_section',array(
        'title' => esc_html__('Slider Settings','customslide'),
        'description'   => esc_html__('Add slider images here.','customslide'),
        'priority'      => null
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('num_of_slides'.$i,array(
        'default'   => esc_html__('2','customslide'),
        'transport' => 'refresh',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
));

$wp_customize->add_control('num_of_slides',array(
        'label' => esc_html__('Number of Slides','customslide'),
        'section'   => 'slider_section',
        'type'  => 'text'
));


$num_of_slides_value = esc_html(get_theme_mod('num_of_slides','2'));

for ($i=1; $i<$num_of_slides_value+1; $i++) {
    // Slide Image i
    $wp_customize->add_setting('slide_image'.$i,array(
        'default'   => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/slides/slider'.$i.'.jpg',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'slide_image'.$i,
            array(
                'label' => esc_html__('Slide Image '.$i.' (1440x700)','customslide'),
                'section' => 'slider_section',
                'settings' => 'slide_image'.$i
            )
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_setting('slide_title'.$i,array(
            'default'   => esc_html__('Responsive Design','customslide'),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('slide_title'.$i,array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Slide Title '.$i,'customslide'),
            'section'   => 'slider_section',
            'type'  => 'text'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('slide_desc'.$i,array(
            'default'   => esc_html__('This is description for slider one.','customslide'),
            'sanitize_callback' => 'customslide_format_for_editor',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('slide_desc'.$i,array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Slide Description '.$i,'customslide'),
            'section' => 'slider_section',
            'setting'   => 'slide_desc'.$i,
            'type'  => 'textarea'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('slide_link'.$i,array(
            'default'   => '#link'.$i,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('slide_link'.$i,array(
            'label' => esc_html__('Slide Link '.$i,'customslide'),
            'section'   => 'slider_section',
            'type'      => 'text'
    ));

}
```

Comment: Have you read the docs about the Customizer API? There are two sections that explain two different methods of refreshing. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/

Comment: Helpful link with the important anker - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#selective-refresh-fast-accurate-updates

Comment: @Nath & bueltge Those are both refresh methods for the preview of the website, and not refreshing the customizer panel itself. The OP asks about how to refreshing the Customizer panel.

Comment: I was looking for the same. I have different modules that I can activate/deactivate from the customizer, but the panel (or entire page) needs to be refreshed for each module's options to appear/disappear after activation/deactivation.

Answer (score 2):

In the current Wordpress version this is not possible, unless you hard write some JS code to dynamically update the customizer panel with your values.
I've opened a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39040) to update menu locations when switching navigation style, check out it.